# JSON response is empty in chrome console CodeIgniter

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, rest, jqgrid

I am facing weird issue while accessing for json response.

When i access url : http://testproject/api/index.php/admin_customers/

**JSON Response:**

```
[{"name":'abc'}, {"name":'def'}, "name":'xyz'}]
```

But when i try to do the same from ajax with jqgrid, i am not receiving any data.

**My Controller Code:**

```
class Api extends CI_Controller {
  public function admin_customers(){
    $query = "select * from customer";
    $rows = $this->db->query($query);
    $array_rows = $rows->result();
    $json_data = json_encode($array_rows);
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo $json_data;
  }
}
```

No luck even after tried as:

```
return $this->output
            ->set_content_type('application/json')
            ->set_status_header(200)
            ->set_output($json_data);
```

Output Response In Console:

[image]

My jQgrid JavaScript Code is:

```
   $("#data-grid").jqGrid({
        url:'http://localhost/testproject/index.php/api/admin_customers/',
        mtype: "GET",
        datatype: "json",
        colModel: [
            { label: 'Name', name: 'name', key: true, width: 75, editable: true}
        ],
        editurl:'http://localhost/testproject/api/admin_customers_edit/',
        viewrecords: true,
        height: 250,
        rowNum: 20,
        pager: "#jqGridPager"
    });
```

What am i doing wrong?

No matter of jQgrid, it is not displayed in response itself in chrome console.

Comment: And where is js code?

Comment: Is the file with JavaScript code from **the same origin**? I mean: can you replace URLs `'http://localhost/testproject/index.php/api/admin_customers/'` to something like `'testproject/index.php/api/admin_customers/'`? It could be that you have [same origin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) problem.

Comment: Yes it is from same domain. I copied all my projects folder to a different folder also and tried by using http://localhost/testproject-api/api/admin_customers for rest call and i am using the http://localhost/testproject/, but still the same issue seen. Is it because of localhost? How to handle this situation. All files should be served from the same domain itself as we have no other option for now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Oleg was rite, it was cross origin scripting error. So i finally managed to do it by allowing cross origin scripting by sending extra header content as below:

```
   public function admin_customers(){
        $query = "select * from customer";
        $rows = $this->db->query($query);
        $data = $rows->result();
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET");
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, OPTIONS");
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding");
        echo json_encode($data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
    }
```

This solved my problem finally :)

But this is security issues. We have to authorize the tokens here as well if i am not wrong.